# Android - App Minimization Handling

Tags: android, bundle, minimize, savestate

I don't believe it is called minimization, but basically when the user navigates away from my game, is there an easy way to pause it? The only thing I know of is bundles, IE restoreState(Bundle savedState)

The problem is, I find myself trying to all sorts of logic problems on variables like this:

```
xGrid = new float[savedState.getFloatArray("xGrid").length];
yGrid = new float[savedState.getFloatArray("yGrid").length];
xGrid = savedState.getFloatArray("xGrid");
yGrid = savedState.getFloatArray("yGrid");
```

Is there an easier way like just stopping the thread and resuming it when they return? This is awfully annoying, considering my app is still in development and I have to update this every time I add a variable. I know i'm a lazy programmer, but... that's the point of programming right? (To be lazy.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way tom , you will need to store all your data , possibly even to a file/database and it will be a great feature to return to a game  after a few days , even after a restart.

The reason you have to store data is Android handles the memory,due to which it can decide to kill your app in an attempt to free memory.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`Activity.onPause()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) and [`Activity.onResume()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onResume%28%29). If you need to save persistent state, check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#SavingPersistentState) on that.